# @CucumberOptions in cucumber-junit-platform-engine

Tags: java, cucumber, junit5, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I'm trying to migrate my cucumber tests from `cucumber-junit` to `cucumber-junit-platform-engine` to be able to use new platform features. How do I redefine my runner to use old `@CucumberOptions`. I'm investigating the issue but can't seem to find the proper way yet.

Before I used such options:

```java
@CucumberOptions(
  plugin = ...,
  features = ...,
  tags = ...,
  glue = ...
)
```

Is there a straighforward way to migrate it to platform-engine?

Comment: In my case, to use the `plugin` option, had to declare it in `cucumber.properties`, under `src/test/resources` as `cucumber.plugin=<package_under_src_test_java>.<class_name>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have been looking into **JUnit5** and **Cucumber 7.0** the past few days, I am only adding to your own answer..
documentation is scarce, this [link](https://palashray.com/example-of-creating-cucumber-based-bdd-tests-using-junit5-and-spring-dependency-injection/) has been a bless and [docs](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/junit-platform-engine#configuration-options)

you dont have to use `@IncludeEngines`
also notice how packages are referenced

```
@Suite
@SelectClasspathResource("com/rmdaw/cucumber/features")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "com.rmdaw.repository")
```

last thing you can place configuration into **test/java/resources/junit-platform.properties** inside you can have something like this:

```
cucumber.publish.quiet=true
cucumber.glue=com.rmdaw.cucumber
cucumber.plugin=pretty,\
            html:target/SystemTestReports/report.html,\
            json:target/SystemTestReports/report.json,\
            junit:target/SystemTestReports/junit.xml\
```

Answer (score 3):

Until [Junit5/#2416](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/pull/2416) is merged there is no 1-to-1 replacement. However if you only have a single class annotated with `@CucumberOptions` adding properties to [`junit-platform.properties`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/junit-platform-engine#configuration-options) should suffice.

EDIT: #2416 was merged and released. You can now use suites to run cucumber with different configurations. See [cucumber-junit-platform docs](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/junit-platform-engine#suites-with-different-configurations).

Comment: What about projects with multiple runners? And how do I define `features = ...,`? I can't find such property for new library. I'll read about test discovery and try to figure it out. If you know how to do it then I'll appreciate help.

Comment: You'll have to start JUnit 5 multiple times with different discovery selectors.

Comment: You can read about that in the Junit documentation. And then you'll have to map that to Maven/Gradle. https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api-discovery

Comment: This might be silly but where do I put the selector code? Let's say I had my feature files in some dir. When I used @CucumberOptions it was easy `features=classpath:some/dir`. Now I think I need to use URISelector but where do I actually put it?

Comment: I asked more specific question about `features` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64676559/feature-files-discovery-in-cucumber-junit-platform-engine).

Comment: Cheers. That helps!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `@Suite` from [junit-platform-engine](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/junit-platform-engine#suites-with-different-configurations) with proper engine should be used instead of cucumber annotations.

```java
@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("features")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "com.example")
public class RunCucumberTest {
}
```

Kudos to @spmason [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70032272/10950272).