# Feature files discovery in cucumber-junit-platform-engine

Tags: java, gradle, cucumber, junit5, cucumber-junit

In `cucumber-junit` library I use `@CucumberOptions` to define feature files location:

```java
package com.mycompany.cucumber;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
  plugin = ...,
  features = "classpath:.", // my java step definitions are in package com.mycompany.cucumber 
                            // but feature files directly in test resources 
                            // resources/is_it_friday_yet.feature
  tags = ...,
  glue = ...
)
public class CucumberRunner {
}
```

I'm running my tests with custom gradle task `cucumberTest`

```
cucumberTest {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

After migrating to `cucumber-junit-platform-engine` `@CucumberOptions` are no longer supported.

```java
package com.mycompany.cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Cucumber;
@Cucumber
public class CucumberRunner {
}
```

I can make it work with replacing `plugin`, `tags`, `glue` options with properties `cucumber.filter.tags`, `cucumber.glue`, `cucumber.plugin`.

What about `features` property? It works fine if I change feature files location to match package name i.e. `resources/com/mycompany/cucumber/is_it_friday_yet.feature`. Still this is a simple case and I have many more test packages which are not placed in the same locations as source code and I cannot move them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In cucumber-jvm v7 the `@Cucumber` annotation is deprecated and you're encouraged to use the regular `@Suite` annotation. This works for me:

```java
@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("features")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "com.mycompany.cucumber")
public class CucumberIT {
}
```

It picks up all my .feature files under the `features/` dir in my resources folder (classpath)

Purpose of annotations:
@Suite - annotation from JUnit 5 to make this class a run configuration for  test suite.
@IncludeEngines("cucumber") - tells JUnit 5 to use Cucumber test engine to run features.
@SelectClasspathResource("features") - to change the location of your feature files (if you do not add this annotation classpath of the current class will be used).
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "com.mycompany.cucumber") - this annotation specifies the path to steps definitions (java classes).

Docs: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/junit-platform-engine#suites-with-different-configurations

There are various other `@Select*` annotations supported by junit-platform, I assume those work as well (though they're marked as experimental so subject to change): https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#api-evolution-experimental-apis

Comment: What about in cucumber-jvm 6.9.1?

Answer (score 2):

[Gradle doesn't support non-class based test engines](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4252#issuecomment-434217496). However you can create [a custom task that uses the JUnit Platform ConsoleLauncher](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/7f04a28b136e8545206b66bf4b200271805beced/documentation/documentation.gradle.kts#L22-L35). You can then use the [Junit 5 selectors](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-console-launcher-options) that are [supported by Cucumber](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/junit-platform-engine#supported-discovery-selectors-and-filters) to select your features. For example the `FileSelector` with `--select-file`.

```
val consoleLauncherTest by tasks.creating(JavaExec::class) {
    dependsOn("testClasses")
    val reportsDir = file("$buildDir/test-results")
    outputs.dir(reportsDir)
    classpath(sourceSets["test"].runtimeClasspath)
    main = "org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher"
    args("--select-file", "path/to.feature")
    args("--details", "tree")
    args("--reports-dir", reportsDir)
}
```

Comment: I made it for now by using matching path to features and source code but I will try to test it later, thx.

Comment: @m-p-korstanje is there any rationale why `features` has been removed from [properties](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/junit-platform-engine#configuration-options)? Would it be ok to request such functionality in `cucumber-junit-platform-engine`?

Comment: Test discovery is a feature provided by the JUnit Platform. As such the Cucumber integration with the JUnit Platform can not provide it. You'd replace `cucumber.features` with the appropriate selector. https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api

Comment: I'm still not convinced, as per docs`Cucumber will scan the package of a class annotated with @Cucumber for feature files.` So why can't this behaviour be overriden by `features` property to scan not the package of the runner but custom user provided package? I have many runners which scan all resources, i.e. `features = "."` and then filter the tests by tags.

Comment: As I wrote in the docs, the annotation is a workaround for the lack of support from Gradle and Maven. I reckon that once supported the annotation will be deprecated. Consider using a custom Gradle job with the JUnit ConsoleLauncher.

Comment: You may also benefit from the ability to run JUnit5 Suites programmatically once 
https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/pull/2416 is merged.

Comment: the amount of work in the PR is absolutely staggering!