# How to run unit tests (non-cucumber) and Cucumber tests (Junit5 based) separately with maven in Spring Boot 3 project?

Tags: java, maven, junit5, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

Problem: When using newer version of Cucumber & Junit5 with cucumber-junit-platform-engine, mvn test runs both unit tests and integration tests. We can no longer run them separately, and I'm looking for a way to fix this.

We had unit tests running om mvn test and cucumber integration tests on mvn verify with the surefire and failsafe plugin. After update to Junit5 and Cucumber 7.15.0 we now use cucumber-junit-platform-engine for maven to discover the cucumber tests. The problem is, that we no longer have the option to run these tests separately. Both mvn test and mvn verify run all the tests (unit tests and cucumber tests) together.

**How can we make a distinction between running the unit tests on mvn test and the cucumber integration tests on mvn verify?**

Project structure:

```
- src
   |-integration-test
      |-resources with feature files, and application.yml for tests
      |-java
         |-com.project.package.structure
            |- scenariosteps
            |- CucumberIT.java with @Suite annotation
            |- IntegrationTestConfig with @TestConfiguration annotation
            |- SpringEntry.java
   |-Spring boot 3 project
   |-test
      |-java
         |-com.project.package.structure
            |-our junit5 + mockito unit tests
```

[image]

Dependencies (all spring boot 3 project dependencies omitted)

```
Maven surefire plugin 3.2.5
Maven failsafe plugin 3.2.1

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
                    <version>7.15.0</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
                    <version>7.15.0</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
                    <version>7.15.0</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
                    <version>5.10.1</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
                    <version>1.10.1</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>7.15.0</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
```

I've been looking through docs + stackoverflow on how to do this. When we were using org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider this worked fine, but it looks like io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.DiscoverySelectorResolver overrides everything:

I get this warning when running mvn test, before unit tests and Cucumber tests are executed:

> io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.DiscoverySelectorResolver warnWhenCucumberFeaturesPropertyIsUsed
> WARNING: Discovering tests using the cucumber.features property. Other discovery selectors are ignored!
> Please request/upvote/sponsor/ect better support for JUnit 5 discovery selectors.
> See: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/pull/2498

When I remove cucumber-junit-platform-engine from the dependencies, the following is used. But this fails to pick up the Cucumber tests. Looks like switching back to JUnitPlatformProvider is not an option, since this is no longer compatible with Cucumber tests.

> Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider

My surefire/failsafe config:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>${unit-tests.skip}</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-failsafe-plugin.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <properties>
                        <configurationParameters>
                            cucumber.junit-platform.naming-strategy=long
                        </configurationParameters>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skipTests>${integration-tests.skip}</skipTests>
                            <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
                            <parallel>none</parallel>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Where are you using `cucumber.features`?

Comment: Your suite is also not named correctly.  To be recognized by Failsafe should be `CucumberIT`. https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

Comment: So presumably the incorrect class name causes the tests not to be executed in the verify phase. But then using `cucumber.features` causes them to be executed anyway as Cucumber ignores surefire and failsafe.  So you should fix the class name and replace the `cucumber.features` property with the equivalent `@Select*` annotation from JUnit.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this!
- File is named CucumberIT, this was a typo in the question, I updated the question
- cucumber.features are in junit-platform.properties

Comment: I tried the example you gave here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64676559/feature-files-discovery-in-cucumber-junit-platform-engine
So this would be @SelectClasspathResource("src/integration-test/resources/features"), but I get "TestEngine with ID 'junit-platform-suite' failed to discover tests" without the cucumber-junit-platform-engine as dependency.
No change with using cucumber-junit-platform-engine, just runs all the tests incl. unit tests at mvn test

Comment: Remove `cucumber.features`. Assuming you've configured Maven correctly, only the path after `src/integration-test/resources` is on your classpath. So you should use `@SelectClasspathResource("features")` instead.

Comment: To confirm: I deleted the line for cucumber.features  and added @SelectClasspathResource("features") to Cucumber IT. 
This does pick up the integration tests on verify, but unfortunately, runs these twice!
Logging shows: 
`failsafe:3.1.2:integration-test (default) @ projectname ---
[INFO] Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider
---
[INFO] Running com.project.integration.CucumberIT ->Cucumber tests run`
And then immedately after the same thing again: 
`[INFO] --- failsafe:3.1.2:integration-test (integration-tests) @projectname
etc`

Comment: I added the surefire/failsafe config. Without the cucumber-junit-platform-engine in failsafe I still get a `CucumberIT » NoTestsDiscovered Suite [com.package..CucumberIT] did not discover any tests` failure.

Comment: Looks like you have a pretty complicated project. You may to start with a smaller project to eliminate some noise. You can use the https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton to start. See if you can make that work with failsafe first.

Comment: Thanks, your comments led me to the solution in the end!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I endend up doing:

To fix the problem where `mvn test` ran both unit and cucumber integration tests, and we got the `io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.DiscoverySelectorResolver warnWhenCucumberFeaturesPropertyIsUsed` warning when running mvn test/verify I used @M.P. Korstanje's solution:

Removed the cucumber.features from junit-platform.properties.
And for CucumberIT.java:

```
@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("features")
// Worked the same as the line above: @ConfigurationParameter(key = FEATURES_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "src/integration-test/resources/features")
public class CucumberIT {
}
```

Dependencies:

```
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
                    <version>7.15.0</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
                    <version>7.15.0</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
                    <version>7.15.0</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>7.15.0</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
```

My surefire and failsafe:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>${unit-tests.skip}</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <properties>
                        <configurationParameters>
                            cucumber.junit-platform.naming-strategy=long
                        </configurationParameters>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skipTests>${integration-tests.skip}</skipTests>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

The final problem was Failsafe kept running the integration tests twice, this turned out to be a bit of old config `<runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder><parallel>none</parallel>` just below `<skipTests>${integration-tests.skip}</skipTests>` in the failsafe plugin.

Comment: Cool! What was the rationale for using `cucumber.features` in the first place? Maybe the warning can be improved.

Comment: It was how our tester did the config after he upgaded Cucumber. I asked him but he did not save the sources he used. I've seen some tutorials using cucumber.feature like this.
I knew we needed to use cucumber-junit-platform-engine for the integration tests to be discovered, but I did not know the CucumberIT config was incorrect (because the integration tests executed, just not in the right spot). I was looking at https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine, which did not help. I will pass on the skeleton repo to our tester :)

Comment: Ah, an upgrade, that would explain it. I guess they mapped all the @CucumberOptions values.